# How to sort dataframe rows in python according to a subset of values contained in a column

Tags: python, sorting

I want to order a dataframe rows according to the values contained in the first column. The first column contains strings and I am interested in some numbers contained in those strings (ie. "chr5:10..100", "chr14:2..300", "chrX:1..10" from these strings I want to collect the chromosome number 5, 14, X). The numbers that I want to extract determine the order I want my rows. Initial and final position of numbers of interest in the strings are not known (the first pos is always 3, but the final is determined finding the ":" symbol.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Strings': ["chrA:2..300", "chr5:10..100", "chr14:2..300",
                               "chrX:2..300", "chrM:2..300", "chr1:1..10"]})  # sample data

to_sort = df['Strings'].str.extract(r'^chr(.+):', expand=False)  # extract symbols between chr and :
nums = to_sort.str.isnumeric()  # make a boolean mask: numeric strings is True, other - False
to_sort[nums] = to_sort[nums].astype(int)  # convert numeric strings to integers
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([~nums, to_sort])
# sort df by level 0 index (for grouping numbers and letters), then by level 1 index (inside numbers, inside letters)
df = df.sort_index(ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        Strings
0    chr1:1..10
1  chr5:10..100
2  chr14:2..300
3   chrA:2..300
4   chrM:2..300
5   chrX:2..300
```

Comment: It works but as we are dealing with alphanumeric data this method is not able to order correctly in cases such as ["chrX", "chrM", "chrY", "chr2", "chr15"...].